# Is there a way to delete a event listener that is in the DOM of a page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am wondering if there is a way of deleting a Event Listener using Javascript and I can't use removeEventListener() because I am not the one that made the Event Listener, it's already in the code of the website when I open it and I need it to be automatically removed so that the popup message does not prompt (It's very annoying when I have to delete 1000 things and a message comes up every time say "Do you want to delete these assets?").

My process that I take is:

1. I open the page (Already has an Event listener)
2. Proceed to delete assets (From a form)
3. Then when I click the submit on the page it has an Event listener attached to it (The one I need to get rid of when I open the page)
4. Then the Event Listener prompts and return confirm("Do you want to delete these assets?") (Very annoying)

Any idea on how I would delete this even listener that's on the page and is not opened by me?

Here is a picture of what the event listener looks like:

[image]

If you do help I thank in advance!

Comment: How to remove an event listener depends on how the listener is originally attached.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. Do not just show a screenshot of something inspected via dev tools, that is not a proper way to describe a problem to begin with.

Comment: Removing an event handler using removeEventListener, requires access to the exact function object that was used to bind the handler with addEventListener in the first place. Maybe you can go for a much simpler solution here - add your own button, that calls the `submit` method of the form - doing that, does _not_ trigger the form `submit` handlers.

Comment: If the listener is added with native `addEventListener`, and you don't have a reference to the handler function, the only way to remove that listener is to recreate the element the listener is attached to (clone the original, then remove it and insert the clone to the DOM). However, it's possible, that this will break some other functionalities on the page.

Comment: Most of the times I read this question, I suspect an X/Y problem

Comment: @mplungjan The use-case is well-described in the question, though.

Comment: Sounds like a bookmarklet could remove the function called by the event handler or rewrite the confirm method

Answer (score 0):

Found a different way of doing it with a bit of search and I am just gonna placebo confirm it with this code:

```
const realConfirm = window.confirm;
window.confirm = function() {
  window.confirm = realConfirm;
  return true;
};
```

Very simple and easy thanks for all the response sorry if the question was bad but thanks for the help lead me to the figuring it out.

P.S @CBroe I will read both of those for future questions sorry